# How to stretch programmatically created columns with HorzontalScroll View

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Hello I been looking around for an answer but for some reason most of the answers that i find do not help me. I have created a tablelayout on my fragment and I am adding a simple tablerow with a text view programmatically. Currently there are 5 or more columns which seem to be packed into the left corner Is there any way to stretch accross the view? thank you for you help!

Update: removing the Horizontal view fixes the problem, however is there a way to make the table stretch with horizontal scrolling? or would I have to manually add a width for each cell?

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3d455b">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hscrll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/entries"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/row_cell">
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
 valuesTable.removeAllViews();

    //add header
            TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(ctx);
            tbrow0.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TextView tv0 = new TextView(ctx);
            tv0.setText("Id");
            tv0.setTextSize(20);
            tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv0.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            tbrow0.addView(tv0);
TextView tv0 = new TextView(ctx);
            tv0.setText("name");
            tv0.setTextSize(20);
            tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv0.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            tbrow0.addView(tv0);
TextView tv0 = new TextView(ctx);
            tv0.setText("color");
            tv0.setTextSize(20);
            tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv0.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            tbrow0.addView(tv0);


            valuesTable.addView(tbrow0);

            //Add row information

                TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(ctx);
                tbrow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                for(String value : row.getValues()){
                    TextView t1v = new TextView(ctx);               
                    t1v.setText(value);
                    t1v.setTextSize(17);
                    t1v.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
                    t1v.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tbrow.addView(t1v);
                }

                valuesTable.addView(tbrow);
```

Comment: To my mind `HorizontalScrollView` is causing the issue

Comment: @NikaKurdadze thats exactly what it was thank you!

Comment: @NikaKurdadze do you have an idea on how to allow stretching when using this two scrolling views?